# Why did Isaac reaped a hundredfold first and God blessed him later?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-chaye-sara

In the verse [Genesis.26.12?](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.26.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en):

> וַיִּזְרַע יִצְחָק בָּאָרֶץ הַהִוא וַיִּמְצָא בַּשָּׁנָה הַהִוא מֵאָה שְׁעָרִים וַיְבָרֲכֵהוּ ה'׃ - Isaac sowed in that land and reaped a hundredfold the same year and the LORD blessed him.

Isaac reaps first and then God blesses him after, whereas I would expect that God bless him first and as the result of that blessing he gets a hundredfold.

Do the commentators address the issue?

Comment: Presumably because it is a continuation of the bracha that Hashem first gave to his father Avraham - see Sforno https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.26.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sforno_on_Genesis.26.12.2&lang2=bi